# Empty $_POST variables causing undefined index

Tags: php, html

I have a login.html page with a form. The form takes in username and password and then calls the home.php page. The `home.php` page assigns the username and password to a variable.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

I also have a `changepassword.html` form page which takes in oldpassword and newpassword and calls the changepassword.php page.

The `changepassword.php` page assigns the old and new passwords to variables:

```
$oldpassword = $_POST["oldpassword"];
$newpassword = $_POST["newpassword];
```

On this page, I also have a link to go back to the home.php page but when I click on it, it gives me the following two error lines:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in [path] on line 19
Notice: undefined index: password in [path] on line 20
```

I suspect that this is because changepassword.html form did not have those variables so it never got saved on `$_POST`.

So when I am calling the home page from changepassword.php page (instead of the `login.html` page), there is nothing to assign to those variables.

I want to get rid of those errors but dont know how. I would have thought when I logged in originally, `session_start()` would have saved username and password.

I have `session_start()` at the start of all files (dont know if that is correct).

Comment: Surely you have the username available (or can get it from the database) when you change the password. And you do have the password. It's just a matter of providing them to the destination script, which expects it as a POST, so you'll need to create a form with that data as hidden inputs.

Comment: argh, its like other posts that have the same question hide while I am researching it and all come out after I post it :(

Comment: Try putting `@` sign just before the variables. Like: @$username

Comment: Note that if `home.php` is indeed a "home page" where users can go back in many cases (other than just after login), checking the username and password at this point is not a good idea. You should have another script to validate the username/password which then sets some sort of authentication token, and only that token should be checked by any of the login-protected pages.

Comment: @OzanKurt wow... magic. It worked. Thanks heaps! Going to look it up now to see what it did.

Comment: @jcaron ah I see. Thanks for that. Ill research that bit. Cheers!

Comment: @HoGil Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a simple ternary condition:

```
$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
$password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : "";
```

So you need to make sure of three things then:

1. The `<form>` method. It should be always set to `method="post"`.
2. The `<input />` element. It should have explicit name, `name="username"`.
3. The `required` attribute: This ensures that empty data is not sent.

So finally, a sample of your code should have:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" required="required" />
</form>
```

***Note:*** I left out all the unnecessary elements.

You also do have another way to do this. By using the warning suppressing mechanism. Put an `@` symbol before the error causing syntax. In this case, the `$_POST`:

```
$username = @$_POST["username"];
$password = @$_POST["password"];
```

But this is not recommended. So use it carefully.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen Kumar

Comment: @HoGil You are welcome.